# NodeJS - Controller not returning JSON to Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

So I have created a Controller to create a user profile, everything works fine, it creates it in the Database, but I can't get anything on the response...At first I thought it was my Route but after some testing by adding a test response early on in the method in the Controller, It returns fine. I am not sure what I am missing as, like I said it enters into the DB fine.

Here is my Controller.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
  var mod = {
     createMerchantUser(req, res) {
       var merchantDescription = 'Merchant for ' + req.body.email;

       ////////// If I add a test Response HERE it returns perfectly
       /////////  return{ message: "Testing response here..." }


     // ANYTHING BELOW GETS CREATED IN DATABASE BUT DOESN'T PROVIDE A RESPONSE
       var merchant = stripe.customers.create({
         email: req.body.email,
         description: merchantDescription
       }, function(err, customer) {

         var new_merchant_user = new MerchantUser({
           email: req.body.email,
           password: req.body.password,
           accountConfirmed: false,
           stripeID: customer.id
         });

        new_merchant_user.save(function(err, merchantUser) {

           if (err) {
             if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
             // Duplicate username
                return res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'An account with this email already exists!' });
             }
           }

           res.json({
             data: {
               merchantUser
             }
           });
         });
       });
     }
   }
   return mod;
};
```

Here is my Route.js

```
  app.post('/api/createMerchUser', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(merchantUsersController.createMerchantUser(req, res))
  })
```

UPDATE:

Just for more context. Below is different way I used to do it, which would work perfectly. It returned the object after creating it. The problem with doing it this way is I can not called methods in different controllers, therefore I had to go with the method above...

Controller.js

```
exports.create_merchant_user = function(req, res) {
  var merchantDescription = 'Merchant for ' + req.body.email;

  var merchant = stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.email,
    description: merchantDescription
  }, function(err, customer) {

    var new_merchant_user = new MerchantUser({
       email: req.body.email,
       password: req.body.password,
       accountConfirmed: false,
       stripeID: customer.id
    });

    new_merchant_user.save(function(err, merchantUser) {

      if (err) {
        if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
        // Duplicate username
            return res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'An account with this email already exists!' });
        }
      }

      res.json({
        data: {
          merchantUser
        }
      });
    });
  });

};
```

Route.js

```
  app.route('/api/merchantUser')
    .post(merchantUsers.create_merchant_user);
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging `merchantUser` in your controller?

Comment: Yes everything posts fine and the Object enters the database - I get 200, so the save function is no issue, it is the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an else block

```
if (err) {
    if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
        // Duplicate username
        return res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'An account with this email already exists!' });
    }
} else {

    return res.json({
        data: {
            merchantUser
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well as the answer above and again unfortunately it is the same outcome, it writes to the database but no response.

Comment: try console logging `merchantUser`  right before  ` res.json({
             data: {
               merchantUser
             }`

Comment: merchantUser Object is all there. Even by adding return, still no response

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the data to the route in your controller.
Use `return` keywrord.

```
 return res.json({
             data: {
               new_merchant_user
             }
           });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is the same outcome, it writes to the database but no response.

Comment: Try to return the response outside the ```save``` function. May be that will help

Comment: Doing it outside doesn't help it unfortunately

Comment: You need to return the ```new_merchant_user``` object outside the save function. Because it actually holds the data. Try this once.

Comment: Yes this returns the object everytime, but it returns it even when an error occurs therefore it isn't producing the desired outcome. If you see my updated question and see how my old method worked. My new method should produce the desired output but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
return res.status(200).type('application/json').send({
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "statusMsg": "success, 
                    "data": merchantUser
                });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help the situation.

Comment: You can specify your route as follows if you want: app.post('/api/createMerchUser', merchantUserController.createMerchantUsers) and then in your controller file you can use the above res.send() code

Comment: It still doesn't return the JSON...Seems to be an issue within the .create or .save calls as returning outside of those works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 304 Status Code?

if so, then,

> A 304 Not Modified response code indicates that the requested resource
>   has not been modified since the previous transmission. This typically
>   means there is no need to retransmit the requested resource to the
>   client, and a cached version can be used, instead.

Try changing your data while making get request then see if you get data on response or not.

Comment: I checked your code again,
is your database adding row after the API call?

If, yes, then returning `[]` is perfectly normal as this is a .save() function.

Comment: But I need it to return the object so I can use it?

Comment: Then you need to make another .find query inside your .save.

`{
           email: req.body.email,
           password: req.body.password,
           accountConfirmed: false,
           stripeID: customer.id
   }`

you could use any of the unique value from the object to find.

Comment: If you look at my updated question, it would return the object fine one save the old way. No find was required so I am not sure why it is needed now?